# How to get api token to access dialogflow in python

Tags: python, google-api, google-oauth, dialogflow-es

Im not sure how I can usemy service account and Dialogflow API key to get an API token using OAuth2 to get an access token for google. Could someone share a code snippet

I want to access this API: https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/reference/rest/v2/projects.agent.entityTypes/list

Answer (score 0):

In order to use the Dialogflow API (in this case, [list all the entity types](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/reference/rest/v2/projects.agent.entityTypes/list) in the specified agent) you have to:

1. [Enable](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/quick/setup#api) the Dialogflow API for your project
2. Go to the Create [service account](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials/serviceaccountkey) key page. From the **Service account** list, select **New service account**, enter a name in the **Service account name** field.
3. From the **Role** list, select Project > Owner.
4. Click **Create**. A JSON file that contains your key downloads to your computer.
5. Once you have the JSON file, you need to [set an environment variable](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/quick/setup#auth-env) in a shell session `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="/path/to/key.json"`.

You can access the API via [REST](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/reference/rest), [gRPC](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/reference/rpc) or a [client library](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/reference/libraries/overview). In this repository, there are some [samples](https://github.com/googleapis/python-dialogflow/tree/master/samples/snippets) with the python client library.

Comment: I do not think that setting the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS environmental variable works with REST V2 API. I set the environment variable through windows cmd and then ran a cURL get to "https://dialogflow.googleapis.com/v2/projects/<ID>/agent/entityTypes. I received a 401 with this error message "Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project."

Comment: You are right! sorry for my misunderstanding. If you want to access the Dialogflow API with a CURL, it is needed the token obtained in the shell console by using the following command `gcloud auth application-default print-access-token`. You can see the CURL request examples [here](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/quick/api)

Comment: The complete request from GCP shell should be like:
`curl --header "Authorization: Bearer "$(gcloud auth application-default print-access-token) --header "Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8" https://dialogflow.googleapis.com/v2/projects/[project-id]/agent/entityTypes`